# Mesos Configuration with existing Apache Spark standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, mesos

I am  a beginner in Apache-spark!
I have setup Spark standalone cluster using 4 PCs.
I want to use Mesos with existing Spark standalone cluster. But I read that I need to install Mesos first then configure the spark.

I have also seen the Documentation of Spark on setting with Mesos, but it is not helpful for me.

So how to configure Mesos with existing spark standalone cluster?

Comment: While you can't use standalone with Mesos (but rather instead, as explained in the answer below) if you want to try out Spark on Mesos, the easiest way is https://dcos.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mesos is an alternative cluster manager to standalone Spark manger. You don't use it with, you use it instead of.

- to create Mesos cluster follow https://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/
- make sure to distribute Mesos native library is available on the machine you use to submit jobs
- for cluster mode start Mesos dispatcher (`sbin/start-mesos-dispatcher.sh`).
- submit application using Mesos master URI (client mode) or dispatcher URI (cluster mode).